# Remove Duplicates from csv

Tags: python

I have a csv/txt file of following content:

```
Mumbai 2
Pune 6
Bangalore 8
Pune 10
Mumbai 8
```

and I want this in output file :

```
Mumbai 2,8
Pune 6,10
Bangalore 8
```

Note : Don't use any python modules, packages

Comment: It is your homework for a reason.

Comment: yes I have solve it by using pandas but without using pandas i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: @Gajanan There's a [protocol for asking about homework questions on this site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @Nils OP specified that no python modules should be used, I suspect that this includes csv.

Comment: with open('Input.txt', 'r') as file:
    text = file.readlines()
    states = {}
    for i in range(len(text)):
        values = text[i][-2:]
        state = text[i][:-2]
        if state in states.keys():
            states[state].append(int(values))
        else:
            states[state] = [int(values)]
            
    print(states)

Comment: with open('Output.txt', 'w') as file:
    for key, value in states.items():
        str1 = ''
        for i in value:
            if len(value)>1:
                str1 += str(i)
                values = ','.join(list(str1))
            else:
                values = str(value[0])
        file.write(key + ' ' + values + '\n')

Comment: @Ben Grossman not even `os`, `re`? *sigh*, this is a difficult homework... (I have deleted my comment because the csv module may not fit, as the city names may have spaces in their names, so regular expressions have to do the job)

Comment: @GajananKoli It's difficult to read code in comments, please [edit] your question and add that in

Comment: You're trying to get unique values based on the key as city names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```py
import re

linepat = re.compile('''

  ^ \s*
  (?:
    (
      [A-Za-z] \S*
      (?: \s+ [A-Za-z] \S* )*
    ) \s+ ( [0-9]+ )
    \s* $
  )
  |
  (.*)

''', re.VERBOSE)

filtered = {}

# fill `filtered` from `duplicates.csv`
with open('duplicates.csv', 'r') as f:
  for lnum, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
    city, number, invalid = linepat.match(line).groups()
    if not city:
      invalid = invalid.strip()
      if invalid:
        raise Exception(f'line {lnum} has a wrong format:\n{line}')
    else:
      city = ' '.join(city.split())
      if city not in filtered:
        filtered[city] = set()
      filtered[city].add(int(number))

# write `filtered` to `without_duplicates.csv`
with open('without_duplicates.csv', 'w') as f:
  for city, numbers in filtered.items():
    numbers = ','.join(str(num) for num in sorted(numbers))
    f.write(f'{city} {numbers}\n')

# Mumbai 2
# Pune 6
# New York 15
#
# Bangalore 8
# Pune 10
# Mumbai 8
# New York 1
#
# -->
#
# Mumbai 2,8
# Pune 6,10
# New York 1,15
# Bangalore 8
```

It is not clear from your example how the numbers per line in the output shall be sorted. If you want them sorted by first occurrence in the input file, use a list instead of a set and do `citynumbers = filtered[city]; if number not in citynumbers: citynumbers.append(number)`, and later have them not `sorted()`.

The whitespaces which separate a city name from its number may also be part of the city name. Therefore the regex requires that every part of the city name starts with `[a-zA-Z]`. Cleaner is, to require that whitespaces are replaced or escaped in city names.

`filtered` in the code example could also be a [defaultdict(set)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

For many use cases, the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) is the simpler approach.